# Origen de la expresión "hasta mañana" y similares

Tags: historia, preposiciones, locuciones, saludos

Ayer mi hijo el mayor me sorprendió con una pregunta que me hizo reflexionar un poco: ¿por qué usamos "hasta" cuando decimos "hasta mañana" o "hasta luego" para expresar que no volveremos a ver a alguien hasta pasado un tiempo?

Según el DLE, la preposición *[hasta](https://dle.rae.es/?id=K2iXUid)* "indica el límite final de una trayectoria en el espacio o en el tiempo". Sin embargo, se me hace raro imaginar de qué expresión podría provenir originalmente:

> —Adiós, ya no nos veremos hasta mañana.
>   —Sí, hasta mañana.

O:

> —Pues ya de aquí hasta que nos veamos.

Buscando en el CORDE desde cuándo se viene usando esta fórmula encuentro lo siguiente:

- Los primeros casos de "hasta luego" parecen ser del siglo XVIII (1715 el primero). Hay casos previos pero no corresponden a la fórmula de despedida, como en "que aguardes hasta luego".
- Lo mismo ocurre con "hasta mañana", aunque encuentro un caso suelto en 1634 en la forma "adiós, pues, hasta mañana".

Pregunto pues, ¿desde cuándo se usa la fórmula "hasta XXX" como despedida? ¿Por qué se usa la preposición *hasta*? ¿Cuál es su origen?

Comment: ¿No se usa "hasta" en todos los idiomas? Inglés "until next time", Alemán "bis nächstes Mal", chino "再見"

Comment: @julodnik puede ser, pero en inglés me parece de uso más común el "see you tomorrow", que no usa la preposición, aunque bien puedo equivocarme. En japonés se usa また 'mata' que no significa "hasta" (eso sería まで 'made'). また あした 'mata ashita' significaría "mañana otra vez", como diciendo "mañana nos veremos de nuevo".

Comment: Es famosa la frase que dijo en español el personaje de Arnold Schwarzenegger en [Terminator 2](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_2:_el_juicio_final):   
**Hasta la vista, baby**

Comment: En inglés se decía anteriormente "until (day)," y quería decir, "Voy a pasar un tiempo sin tí hasta que te vea otra vez, o sea mañana (u otro día)", o "I'm not going to see you until (day)."  También hay "until next time" como dice julodnik, y "until then".  Oddly I couldn't find it in a dictionary but I did find in Word Reference: "I think it's more like a sentence that you use so often that you end up omitting lots of words when you are using it.  "'Till tomorrow, then"-----" (I won't be seeing you) until tomorrow then" (https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/till-tomorrow-then.493833/).

Comment: Also see https://www.italki.com/question/204907

Comment: En italiano: "a domani"; en francés: "à demain". Por lo tanto, el "hasta" no es tan "universal".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **hasta luego,** s.v. *hasta* ( ~ ahora, ~ después, ~ la vista, ~ luego, o ~ más ver. 1. exprs. U. para
>   despedirse de alguien a quien se espera volver a ver pronto o en el mismo día).
>
> Pertenece históricamente al mismo grupo de locuciones formadas mediante preposición +
>   *luego*; el *DRAE* le da la categoría de “expresión” y la incluye en el artículo de *hasta*, no en las locuciones con *luego* (en *NGLE* aparece como locución interjectiva, 32.1.2b, 32.3.1d). La combinación con la preposición *hasta se* documenta primero con el sentido de ‘hasta después, más tarde’ (**1642** Calderón de la Barca, *El divino cazador*: “¿[Q]ué me quieres? […] Que aguardes hasta luego”); la estructura *hasta luego* + infinitivo presentó abundantes testimonios previos a la locución interjectiva (p. ej.: *hasta luego reventarla*). Como saludo de despedida, se emplea desde el siglo XVIII (**1762**, Fernández de Moratín, *La petimetra*: “Adiós, *hasta luego*”) y su grado de fosilización o gramaticalización es desigual en los dialectos<sup>41</sup>. En la definición quizá se podría añadir que también es un modo de despedida en general, de acuerdo con los usos actuales.
>
> ...
>
> <sup><sup>41</sup> 41 Es relativamente reciente la gramaticalización de *hasta luego* en algunas variedades, donde se mantenía el contenido léxico que aporta la preposición *hasta*, que denota el término de algo, en este caso el adverbio de tiempo *luego*, así como el valor temporal de éste. Sin embargo, en el español actual *hasta luego* ha debilitado su significación denotando un modo de despedida que no tiene en cuenta el tiempo del reencuentro. Por otro lado, la variante *hasta lueguito* se usa cada vez más en la lengua coloquial del español de España siendo la única expresión en la que se emplea el diminutivo con el adverbio (en el español peninsular)</sup>

- [La variación de *luego* y su evolución histórica](https://www.academia.edu/5180576/La_variaci%C3%B3n_de_luego_y_su_evoluci%C3%B3n_hist%C3%B3rica_preprint)

Answer (score 1):

En cuanto al origen y el momento en que se empezó a usar esta manera de decir "hasta mañana" yo lo desconozco. De antemano una disculpa por eso. Me gustaría responder sin embargo a la otra parte de tu cuestionamiento del por qué.

Desde mi perspectiva como hablante hispano de nacimiento, efectivamente **hasta** significa el fin de un periodo de tiempo. Así que podría parecer un poco confuso usarlo en ese contexto. Pero piénsalo de esta manera:

Cuando dices "**hasta mañana**", estás estableciendo un tiempo implícito que va *desde el momento en que dejas de tener contacto* con esa persona *hasta el día siguiente que la vuelvas a ver*. Es como si le dijeras de otra forma: Entraremos en un estado en que no vamos a vernos **desde ahora** y **hasta el día de mañana** que nos volvamos a ver.

Espero haber sido claro. Hasta mañana delimita el tiempo que vamos a durar sin vernos con alguien más, por eso el "hasta ese punto en el tiempo". No hablamos de lo que haremos una vez que nos volvamos a ver, sino de cuánto tiempo vamos a permanecer sin vernos.

Ojalá que te haya aclarado el punto del por qué se usa así.